# Persisting data via SCORM in Desire2Learn

Tags: scorm, desire2learn

I am trying to use Shareable State Persistence within a Desire2Learn SCO.  However, it does not seem to be supported.  I get an error 401 (Undefined Data Model Element) when I try to use one of the "ssp.*" with SetValue (e.g.:  ssp.allocate or ssp.data).

Does anybody know how to share custom data between SCOs within Desire2Learn?

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain Desire2Learn doesn't support SSP. In SCORM 2004 4th Edition, there are shared data buckets that allow you to share custom data across SCOs, but (to the best of my knowledge) I don't think Desire2Learn has updated their system to support 4th Edition either.

SCORM Cloud supports both 4th Edition and SSP. You could look into using its [SCORM Dispatch](http://scorm.com/scorm-cloud/dispatch/) feature to run your content in the Cloud and then report the results to your Desire2Learn instance.